# Handling Adsense banners in a responsive layout

Tags: web, adsense, responsive-design

How would one go about handling Adsense banners in a responsive layout?

As far as I can read from the Adsense TOS, I'm pretty much not allowed to do anything client-side with the banners, so I can't, client-side, switch a banner to a smaller one if it's a low resolution.

It seems the only solution I can find is to only serve banners that work in the lowest target resolution (i.e. 300x250).

Anyone with a better idea?

Comment: I am curious about this as well. I wonder if a JavaScript that dynamically chooses the right format would be allowed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should implement [responsive ad units](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/3213689). Modifying AdSense code or implementing tricks mentioned in [my original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/16808101/1) is no longer necessary.

Answer (score 2):

[Boston Globe](http://bostonglobe.com/) solved this problem on their famously responsive site by creating a designated advertising column. That column is set to a fixed width large enough to contain the ad, and the ad is never resized, even as the rest of the page adjusts responsively. It's not ideal, but it keeps the ad intact.

It would be great to just load multiple sizes of ads into multiple places on the page, and show/hide based on page size, but obviously Adsense isn't going to go for that.

Answer (score 1):

Adsense does actually use "responsive" ads of sorts, [as described here](http://adsense.blogspot.com/2012/01/making-ads-smart-adapting-ads-to-device.html). So you should be able to use the larger ad formats and have them shrunk for mobile.

However, I have noticed that they do not really take "responsive design" into account, they only look at the device viewing the page. If you shrunk your browser window you would still see a leaderboard ad (cut off), and similarly on mobile you only see half the ad, even though it uses the Adsense mobile format.

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled upon an [article](http://www.howto-connect.com/change-ad-size-of-adsense-for-mobile-platform-automatically-is-legal/) which clearly states that resizing an ad with javascript is allowed.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use javascript to serve different ads depending on the client. It is the best solution I have found so far.

There is a concise description of it here: http://www.milouchev.com/blog/2013/02/google-adsense-responsive-layout/

It does require you to create multiple different ads instead of just one, for every ad placement. But creating 3 ads instead of 1, should be a small price for increasing your AdSense revenue.